# How to parse nested xml in iPhone?

Tags: xml, ios, ipad, ios4

```
<Row>
<row>1</row>
<priority>Low</priority>
<message>
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE="12" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="1">HIII</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
</message>
<subject></subject>
<status><B><font color='#FF0000'>Mark Read </font></B></status>
<flagstatus>1</flagstatus>
<message_id>78</message_id>
</Row>
```

Message for "Marry" data:

```
<message>
<TEXTFORMAT LEADING="2"><P ALIGN="LEFT"><FONT FACE="Arial" SIZE="12" COLOR="#000000" LETTERSPACING="0" KERNING="1">Marry</FONT></P></TEXTFORMAT>
</message>
```

How to parse this kind of xml format and fetch "Marry" data in the above example.

Any reply is appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use NSScanner, it works both on the iphone and mac. It is a class that basically wraps NSString to be able to scan the string.

You initialize the NSString with your XML source and then you create an NSSCanner object with that string to scan the string in a while loop. ( while( ![scanner isAtEnd] ) )

[NSScanner class reference and how to use](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSScanner_Class/Reference/Reference.html)

Answer (score 0):

To parse xml in iOS, you can also use [NSXMLParser](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/Foundation/Classes/NSXMLParser_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/c_ref/NSXMLParser).
The [Event-Driven XML Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000186i) has details and examples.

Answer (score 0):

http://ioslazyworks.blogspot.in/2013/05/ios-universal-xml-parser.html

This tutorial helps in parsing XML without giving tags in inputs. Its a static library which handles the parsing logic and responds in delegates.

Comment: Note that [link-only answers](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/link-only-answers/info) are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which  tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.